# Restricting allowed keys in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Is there a way to only allow (but not require) keys in a Firebase object? I know you can use `.validate` to ensure that an object has certain keys. Is it possible to *only* allow certain keys, in a whitelist of sorts? If not, it seems like this would be a great way for unwanted/unnecessary data to make it into the database from malicious clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Firebase's *$ variables* to disallow all non-specified children. From the [Firebase guide on securing your data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter), comes this example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "widget": {
      // a widget can have a title or color attribute
      "title": { ".validate": true },
      "color": { ".validate": true },
      // but no other child paths are allowed
      // in this case, $other means any key excluding "title" and "color"
      "$other": { ".validate": false }
    }
  }
}
```

So the `widget` node can have a `color` and/or a `title` property. But if it has any other properties, it will be rejected.

So these are all valid according to these security rules:

```
ref.child('widget').set({ title: 'all is blue' });
ref.child('widget').set({ color: 'blue' });
ref.child('widget').set({ title: 'all is blue', color: 'blue' });
```

But these are invalid according to the rules above:

```
ref.child('widget').set({ titel: 'all is blue' });
ref.child('widget').set({ title: 'all is blue', description: 'more...' });
```